# emacs auto line wrap at 79 characters only in python files

Tags: emacs, newline

I've added this to my Emacs init file:

```
(setq-default auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
(set-default 'fill-column 79)
```

However a new line begins automatically for all files. I would like this functionality only for files ending in `.py`.

Comment: How about using a major-mode hook and just `setq` to set buffer-local values?  Google `python-mode-hook` for some examples.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be working:
 `(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
          (setq auto-fill-function 'do-auto-fill)
          (set-default 'fill-column 79)))`

Comment: Consider changing `(set-default 'fill-column 79)` to `(setq fill-column 79)`

Comment: Please put answers in answer boxes, and use the comment boxes for comments.